# dynamic sequence boxes logic using prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2UAqW/4/

```
    var counter = 1;
$('#add').click(function(){
    var value = ++counter;
    var myHtml = "<div id='boxFirst'>" + value +"</div>";
    $(myHtml).appendTo("#boxFirst");
});
```

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DNR7R/

Code :

```
var counter = 1;
$('#add').click(function(){
    var value = ++counter;
    var myHtml = "<div id='box"+value+"' class='box'>" + value +"</div>";
    $(myHtml).insertAfter("#box"+(value - 1));
});
```

The counter var wasn't initialized. I changed `var value = counter++;` to `var value = ++counter;` in order for the `value` variable to have the already incremented value.

ID were changed to be unique. I concat the value to get id like box1, box2, box3...

In order to be able for your div to put them as you want, I added `display: inline-block` and `float:left` properties to them. For css, i put on them all the same class `box`.

I also remove the `#add` div css to treat it as an other div.

Comment: well.. you need to make sure.. id is unique everytime the div is appended.. :)

Comment: nevermind on the id.. I jst want to find how to create the dynamic append square thingy..

Comment: can the button position be within the box? for example it should be at box 2 position when there is box 1, and so on.. the add button be in the grey area.

Comment: this is the case, no ? Look at the last fiddle I put : http://jsfiddle.net/DNR7R/

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/2UAqW/3/

**JS:-**

```
var counter=2;
$('#add').click(function(){
    var value = counter++;
    var myHtml = "<div class='boxFirst'>" + value +"</div>";
    $("#wrap").append(myHtml);
});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="boxFirst">1</div>

</div>
<div id="add">+</div>
```

**CSS:-**

```
#wrap{
    background-color:#eee;
    width: 200px;
    height 800px;
}

.boxFirst{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:blue;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}

#add{
      width:40px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;  
    background-color:red;
    float: right;
    margin:40px 40px 0  0;
}
```

Comment: omg, how come I never thought of that! The add button should be outside.....!! thx!!

Comment: but the styling became not nice.. when the 2nd element is added, the add button should be at the 3rd box place.. and so on.. is it possible to do that?

Comment: close to that but not really.. for example when it's 3, it should be at the bottom.. It should be the place of 4, at right..